# Macro Accessing struct member without type definition

Tags: c, struct, macros

I bumped into this macro definition.

```
#define CMD_CTX (cmd->ctx)
```

I understand its functionality. it is trying to access the member 'ctx' from struct 'command_invocation' in the following snippet. I knew that because 'command_invocation' is the only struct that has 'ctx' member in my code. what's confusing is why there was no mention for the type of the input argument.

```
struct command_invocation {
    struct command_context *ctx;
    struct command *current;
    const char *name;
    unsigned argc;
    const char **argv;
};
```

Now the call of CMD_CTX is as follows

```
command_context_mode(CMD_CTX, COMMAND_EXEC);
```

and the definition of this function is

```
int command_context_mode(struct command_context *cmd_ctx, enum command_mode mode)
```

I understand the return value matches. But what's not clear for me here is how the input argument is determined in this call "command_context_mode(CMD_CTX, COMMAND_EXEC);"

Comment: At compilation time `CMD_CTX` is simply replaced with `(cmd->ctx)` which is no more than just accessing `ctx` field through `cmd` pointer

Comment: So if the call becomes command_context_mode(cmd ->ctx, COMMAND_EXEC); what is cmd in this case ?

Comment: Most likely, `cmd` is a variable. Unlikely, but can be a macro as well

Comment: where the call to CMD_CTX occurs there is no variable named cmd actually . that's why it is confusing for me

Answer (score 1, accepted):

macros are just named text fragments. So, they just simply gets replaced by their contents before real compilation by a pre-processor. So in your case the call to the function

```
command_context_mode(CMD_CTX,
```

will be replaced with

```
command_context_mode((cmd->ctx),
```

Note that '(' and ')' from the macro definition will be here as well. 
I intentionally did not show the second parameter to the call because it looks like yet another macro which you provided no definition for.

So, macros do not need to know anything about the types, since they only replace text. But the compiler will check for the type matching after the replacement happened.

IMHO, this type of macro use only makes the program more difficult to read and more confusing (as it did for you). Do not use it.

Comment: So in this call command_context_mode((cmd->ctx), I couldn't understand from where cmd is coming since there is no variable named cmd and according to the definition there is no input argument.

Comment: This variable must be defined somewhere in the program, before it is used. So, it is either above the fragment you showed or is in one of the header files which included there. It could be hidden in yet another macro somewhere. you should be able to find it. In the worst case you might run the preprocessor only. It will create a big file with all macros expanded and pointers to the real files. You can find it there.